# The right way to separate /var to another drive?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I have the following instructions from the software that I'll be installing on my machine:

```
SWAP - Refer to the OS vendor recommendation (usually at least the amount of RAM on the server times two).
/ - 20GB minimum, 50GB recommended. This partition will be used for the OS updates.
/tmp - At least 3GB recommended.
/var - The rest of the unallocated disk space.
```

I have the following 2 drives:

```
1. SSD (120GB)
2. HDD (4TB)
```

And of course, I'd like to install everything on the **SSD** and the `/var` on the **HDD**.

---

I'm new in partitioning so I'll be very thankful if someone let me know if I did it correctly.

[image: Screenshot]

**df -h**

```
Filesystem                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                  7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                     7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     7.8G   17M  7.8G   1% /run
tmpfs                     7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-root    56G  2.8G   53G   5% /
/dev/sda1                 2.0G  163M  1.9G   8% /boot
/dev/mapper/centos-tmp    6.0G   33M  6.0G   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/centos00-var  3.7T  293M  3.7T   1% /var
tmpfs                     1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/0
```

**fdisk -l**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0008ca6e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     4196351     2097152   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         4196352   234440703   115122176   8e  Linux LVM
WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.

Disk /dev/sdb: 4000.8 GB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: gpt
Disk identifier: C137EFF4-8B1E-44BE-8877-C03B68E22289


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048   7814035455    3.7T  Linux LVM       

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-root: 59.9 GB, 59898855424 bytes, 116989952 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos-swap: 51.5 GB, 51539607552 bytes, 100663296 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos-tmp: 6442 MB, 6442450944 bytes, 12582912 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos00-var: 4000.8 GB, 4000783007744 bytes, 7814029312 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're fine with the configuration you presented.

good point: the huge /var partition is on a disk using a *gpt* partition table (aka "disk label" - this is the type of partitioning). this is necessary for disks having partions > 2TB size.

another good thing (from my point of view and my experience) is: the installer suggested you to use LVM and you followed this suggestion.  in some situations this will make future changes of partition sizes or  migration of a file system (a "volume") to another disk easier.

As the OS installer did everything for you, don't bother about the extra layer in disk access.